# Javascript to populate an option box with an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-select

Hi was wondering if you could help, i need to use JavaScript to populate the clothes option box with appropriate options when the user specifies what type of gender they are. This is the code I have so far,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var subListArray = [];
subListArray[0] = 'Select a type first';
subListArray[1] = ['skirt', 'dress', 'tights'];
subListArray[2] = ['jeans', 'hat'];
</script>
```

### Person

```
       Gender Type: <select name="genderType" id="genderType" >
      <option value="">Gender Type?</option>
      <option value="girl">Female</option>
      <option value="boy">Male</option>
    </select> </br>

        Clothes <select name="clothType">
      <option value="">Choose a Type</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: And how do you relate gender to specific arrays?

Comment: Are you suggesting that men don't wear [tights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikhail_Baryshnikov)? :P

Comment: @Jason: Cary Elwes made it look good, it's true.

Comment: I dont know how to relate the gender to specific arrays, I was just wanting it so when you select gender type girl that 'skirt', 'dress', 'tights' would appear in the option values on the clothes.

Answer (score 1):

Use objects instead of arrays so that you can map the `subList` to the selected gender.  You don't *have* to do this, but it simplifies things a bit.  Add a "change" listener to the gender selector that creates the option elements for the new select box:

```
var subListArray = {
    'default': ['Select a type first'],
    'girl': ['skirt', 'dress', 'tights'],
    'boy': ['jeans', 'hat'],
};

document.getElementById('genderType').addEventListener('change', function () {
    var sel = document.getElementById('clothType'),
        value = this.value ? this.value : 'default';
    sel.innerHTML = '';
    subListArray[value].forEach(function (item) {
       sel.appendChild(new Option(item));
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VdXk6/

Comment: i am not supposed to alter the array in anyway. Do I just change default, girl, boy back to subListArray[0] subListArray[1] subListArray[2]?

Comment: @user2136922 should be pretty simple; just check `if value == 'boy'` then use `subListArray[2]`, etc.

Comment: where do i put that in the code and what do I replace it with? Thanks

Comment: @user2136922 put it right before `</body>`.  What do you mean by replacing it?

Comment: i mean if i put the if statement in do i need to change any of the code i have used? Would you be ok to add it in as I ain't very good with this? Thanks

Comment: @user2136922 no, you need all of the code you have currently including the html and the `subListArray` definition

Answer (score 0):

See this page which explains adding elements to the DOM:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/dom2.shtml

You need to use createElement, setAttribute and appendChild. E.g:

html:

```
<select id="mySelect">...</select>
<select id="mySubSelect"></select>
```

javascript:

```
var myNewOption = document.createElement( 'option' );
myNewOption.setAttribute( 'value', 'myOptionValue' );
document.getElementById( 'mySubSelect' ).appendChild( myNewOption );
```

This can go in a loop. Also you can detect when the selection changes like this:

javascript:

```
document.getElementById('mySelect').addEventListener('change',function(){
    document.getElementById('mySelect').selectedIndex; // a number showing which element is selected
});
```

With jQuery it is a lot easier.

Comment: Please don't recommend inline javascript event handlers.